# Error linking glsl Program Object

Tags: c++, opengl

Проект компилится, собирается, но проблема такая: на некоторых компьютерах проект работает, на некоторых с дикими тормозами, и постоянно вылезает в отладочную консоль вот такая ошибка:

> error linking glsl Program Object: Недопустимая операция Error: No shaders attached to current program.\

Я так понимаю это проблема связанная с OpenGL?

Comment: по видимому проблему нужно искать в установленной версии opengl драйвера. раз пишет что нет доступных шейдеров

Comment: программа работает исправно на машине, на котороый стоит 3.3 версия, а не подскажете как можно изменить версию opengl?

Comment: Сама длл-ка лежит в C:\windows\system32\ Для начала проверте какую версию опенжл поддерживает видеокарта. затем сравниваете версию драйвера. дальше видней. за одно посмотрите сколько свободной оперативной пямяти. возможно в коде есть крупноразмерный объект который не помещается в память и тд. Так же это возможно что это исключение заложено предыдущим программистом специально

Comment: У меня стоит amd 8490, у меня установлена версия 4.4, ее поставил каталист, с памятью вроде бы все в порядке, смотрел через диспетчер задач - загруженна не полностью.

Comment: если с драйвером и хардом все хорошо. то начинайте копать код

Comment: Если проблема в коде, почему на некоторых компьютерах он работает а на некоторых нет?

Comment: то же самое можно с таким же успехом предъявить и харду с драйверами. я например в свои коды специально вношу исключительные ситуации чтобы при отладке приложения вместо зависонов выскакивала ошибка. может в коде привязка к конкретному железу есть или автоматическая сборка мусора да и много чего навыдумывать можно

Comment: кстати еще совет. насколько я понял glsl переносит часть работы с видеокарты на процессор, советую вам проследить зависимость работы у разных процессоров. может каких нибуть glsl инструкций он не поддерживает

Comment: OpenGL такая штука, что от видюхи и драйверов тоже многое зависит. И не обязательно экстеншены - стандартный функционал тоже частенько работает различно.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, вы используете сбор программы шейдера целиком или раздельно с использованием пайплайнов? Если второе - проверьте, что в вертексном шейдере переопределен gl_Position

```
out gl_PerVertex
{
  vec4 gl_Position;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы Вы могли нарисовать что-нибудь с использованием современного 3D-конвейера, вам понадобятся программы, которые говорят GPU, что делать с вершинами и пикселями. Программы эти называются шейдеры.

В OpenGL "программа" (Program) - это набор шейдеров для выполнения на конвейере.

Так вот, ругается у вас OpenGL при вызове отрисовки, потому что к программе не подключены шейдеры. Вам необходимо с помощью функции [glAttachShader](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glAttachShader.xhtml) подключить скомпилированные шейдеры к программе. В программе должен быть хотя бы один вершинный и один пиксельный шейдер.

В целом, поскольку я не знаю, в каком состоянии Вам достался проект, могу лишь сказать, что вероятно сами шейдеры уже где-то скомпилированы и их осталось просто назначить. Если же нет, то вот код, показывающий, как скомпилировать и подключить шейдер:

```
GLuint ShaderID = glCreateShader(Type); // Это объект шейдера

const char* ShaderText = GetShaderText(); // это будет исходный код шейдера
const GLint Size = GetShaderTextLength(); // это размер кода шейдера в байтах
glShaderSource(ShaderID,1,&Str,&Size); // Устанавливаем исходный код в машину состояний
glCompileShader(ShaderID); // Компилируем его
GLint compiled(0); // Тут будем хранить результат компиляции

glGetObjectParameterivARB(ShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled); // получим состояние компиляции


if (compiled)
{
    // тут код, который работает в случае, когда все хорошо
}
else
{
    // А дальше, когда все плохо
    GLint blen = 0; 
    GLsizei slen = 0;

    glGetShaderiv(ShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH , &blen);       // Получим размер буфера под текст ошибки
    if (blen > 1)
    {
        GLchar* compiler_log = (GLchar*)malloc(blen);
        glGetInfoLogARB(ShaderID, blen, &slen, compiler_log); // Получим сам текст

    // Тут мы делаем с текстом ошибки что-нибудь вроде ::OutpuDebugStringA();

    free (compiler_log); // чистим за собой текст ошибки
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Решил искать проблему в коде! Попробую воспользоваться Вашим решением, по итогам отпишусь!

Comment: Есть еще кое-что, что Вы должны знать. На разных компьютерах разные видеокарты, операционные системы и т.д. Это значит, что на них вам доступны разные [шейдерные модели](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language) Они соответствуют версии OpenGL. Вероятно, из-за несоответствия версии OpenGL на целевой машине и версии, жестко заданной в тексте шейдера словом #version не совпадают, шейдер не компилируется, не передается в программу и в итоге вы видите ваше сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Самое интересное, что ни одну из функций выше и #version я не нашел О_о А может быть такое, что шейдеры скомпилены где - то в другом месте и подключается как библиотека?

Comment: Да, может. Функция [glShaderBinary](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glShaderBinary) загружает байт-код ранее скомпилированного шейдера и отдает его драйверу.